# Python pandas - how to pick out dates from a column and move them over?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

a new python user here.

Say I have column like this. I have dates mixed in with other strings.

```
---------
12/30/19
apple
banana
peach
grapes
berries
1/2/20
chocolate
vanilla
strawberry
1/5/20
cookie
cream
```

How do I make it so that I copy over **only** dates to a new column and forward fill? I have the code to do the forward fill but I'm not sure how to only copy the dates over.

```
---------------------------
12/30/19          12/30/19
apple             12/30/19
banana            12/30/19
peach             12/30/19
grapes            12/30/19
berries           12/30/19
1/2/20              1/2/20
chocolate           1/2/20
vanilla             1/2/20
strawberry          1/2/20
1/5/20              1/5/20
cookie              1/5/20
cream               1/5/20
```

Comment: Can you share the code you already have? This might help us help you!
Namely, are you using `pandas` or some other library?

Comment: @SamuelDion-Girardeau Pandas, as mentioned in the title of my post :) which code are you specifically looking for? I just have a dataframe with aforementioned rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specifically for the cells that have a date, and put them in a new column, then fowardfill:

```
df['col2'] = df.loc[df['col1'].str.contains('\d+\/\d+\/\d+')]
df['col2'] = df['col2'].ffill()
```